# mvc c# with jquery getjson not closing the modal popup but redirects to another page with json result

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

So I'm not sure what's happening here. I have this modal popup that loads a partial view from an action (this might be the problem??) . The partial view loads perfectly and processes fine but once the post ends and should return a json, instead of the modal just closing and then posting the results it redirects me to another page that shows the json results (not the partial view). I'm not entirely sure if the way i'm approaching this is correct. I just need to close the dialog after the action was successfully processed and then return a message if it has either saved the transaction or throw an error.

Any advice is appreciated. thanks!!!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#modal-link').click(function () {
            var href = this.href;
            $('#load-modal-dialog').dialog({
                modal: true,
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).load(href, function (result) {
                        $('#new-registration').submit(function () {
                            $.getJSON(href, function (data) {
                                if (data.success == true) {
                                    $('#messages').html('woo!');
                                } else {
                                    $('#messages').html('dafuq');
                                }
                                this.dialog('close');
                            });
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

my partial view that gets loaded on the popup

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("New", "Registration",  FormMethod.Post, new { id = "new-registration" })){ %>
    <h2>Register Participant:</h2>
    <div class="">
        <%: Html.ValidationSummary(null, new { @class = "" })%>
        <div class="">
            <div class="">Email Address:</div>
            <div class="">
                <%: Html.TextBox("Email", null, new { @class = "" })%>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" value="Submit">Register</button>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

the action

```
public ActionResult New(){
            return PartialView(context.Contest.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == 1));
        }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult New(FormCollection formCollection)
        {
            string email = formCollection["Email"].ToString();

            try
            {
                if (email == "")
                    throw new Exception("Please provide an email address.");

                Registration registration = new Registration
                {
                    ContestId = 1,
                    Email = email
                };

                context.Registration.Add(registration);
                context.SaveChanges();
                return Json(new { success = "true", message = "User succesfully registered to Contest." });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //throw ex;
                return Json(new { success = "false", message = ex.Message });
            }

        }
```

Comment: you might wanna check [this](http://yassershaikh.com/how-to-create-a-modal-popup-in-asp-net-mvc-3-using-jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default action of the link(Opening a new window).Add these lines to your code,

```
 $('#modal-link').click(function (event) {
           //....All content..

           event.preventDefault();// this will stop the opening new page
           event.stopPropergation();
           return false;
   });
```

Comment: try placing this in the `submit` function.

Comment: did that, still the same. also included the "event" insinde the submit function. i tried placing it inside the getJson one too..